# jVectorMap: always show marker tip

Tags: jvectormap

When mouse on the marker,one tip show on the map.is there a way to have the tips always show beside all markers instead only on hover?

Comment: Yes, there is already an example on the jVectorMap website:
[jVectorMap Marker icons](http://jvectormap.com/examples/marker-icons/)